# WHERE clause to restrict rows left join

Tags: oracle, join

I don't understand why these two queries below fetch different count. Case 1 below fetches more rows while Case 2 fetches fewer rows. If the `where` clause is put outside, fewer records are fetched.

Case 1

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1 = 123) A
          LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B ON B.COL2=A.COL4
          LEFT JOIN TABLE3 C ON C.COL3=B.COL2
      )
```

Case 2

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT *  FROM TABLE1 ) A
         LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B ON B.COL2=A.COL4
         LEFT JOIN TABLE3 C ON C.COL3=B.COL2
   ) 
WHERE COL1 = 123
```

Comment: Please post some sample data which reproduces this behavior.

Comment: Theoretically this is possible but without sample data it is difficult to explain the result

Comment: thanks for the reply. however, if you can provide the theoretical explanation that will help too

Comment: (Things that might help: 1) choose a more telling title 2) ask an explicit question 3) have the DB *explain* an *execution plan*)

Comment: Is TABLE1 the only table containing a column called COL1?

Comment: yes only table1 has col1

Comment: If you can see, `A` is alias for Sub-query: `(SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1 = 123)`. So if `TABLE1` has only one column- `COL1` then `LEFT JOIN` condition `B.COL2=A.COL4` must give you an Error. Please check again with your tables and if possible please post your table structures with sample data as asked by others earlier.

Comment: Are you sure you transformed your actual example correctly, when you rewrote it for posting here? I don't think so. If the filter you moved from a subquery to the outer query is on the left table in a left outer join, that move will have no effect. If you say otherwise, please provide a concrete example. (Don't waste your time; just go back to your real-life example and figure out where you translated it incorrectly.)

Comment: `fetch different count` && `fewer records are fetched` - please make it unmistakable: is there a difference in the number of a) "disk" records reported fetched during query processing by the DB or 1) records reported by the outermost `COUNT`.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretical explanation:

Consider a left outer join of tables A and B. A condition (filter) on table B has different effects if it is in the join condition (ON clause) vs. in the WHERE clause. **EDIT**: The filter on B being in the ON condition is equivalent to replacing B with a subquery where the filter is applied first (similar to the OP's example).

If it's in the ON clause, then the rows in table B are filtered for that condition, and then the left join is performed. Then the result of the query will include rows from A (with NULL for the B side) whenever there are no rows in B that satisfy the filter and match the row in A on the join condition.

On the other hand, if the filter on B comes later in the execution, in a WHERE clause, then the left join is performed first. Only then is the WHERE clause applied. The WHERE clause is very likely (depending on the conditions on B) to reject all the rows from A that didn't have a matching row in B - because for such rows, all the values from B are NULL.

In your case, assuming COL1 only exists in table B, then the condition COL1=123 in a WHERE clause will effectively cause the left join to produce the same result as an inner join: any rows from A that didn't have a match in B will come from the left join with COL1 as NULL, so they will fail the filter condition. When you put COL1=123 in the ON clause, that check is done BEFORE the "outer join" operation.

Comment: Semi-neat explanation. It would have been neater if your usage of tables `A` and `B` had matched the OP's rather than flipping them.

Comment: @APC - I intentionally didn't read the OP's example, because he asked for a theoretical explanation. I wasn't even going to add the last paragraph, but after I was done I felt it may be too theoretical.

Comment: @APC - err... now I read the OP's example, and the OP is wrong. THOSE queries should produce the same result, since the filters is on the table on the left of the left join. Such filters can be in the ON or the WHERE clause, it makes no difference. I will ask for clarification.

Comment: yes you are right, i was getting less rows because of some other condition in the query (rank) not because of left join. I was also wondering that how was that possible, in left join placement of where clause in the example should not matter. Thanks !